# how to control the size of a popup box that chrome adds to input type emails in my code for mobile only?

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, popup, autofill

how to control the size of a popup box that chrome adds to input type emails in my code for mobile-only?

I have a form with an input, type email.
when my user starts typing, chrome opens a popup with options from history/cache.
I need to limit the height of this popup as it overlaps the mobile keyboard.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.